# Setting super class properties for subclass

Tags: java, oop, inheritance

So I'm having a bit of an issue getting my properties to set properly in a super class type scenario.

I have 2 classes such that class B is a specialized version of class A, let's say...

```
public class A {
    private String name;
    private int id;
    ...
} 

public class B extends A {
    private Date time;
    private int status;
    ...
}
```

Now what I'm trying to do is use a method that is used to set properties in A from a result set, but instead set them in an instance of B.

```
public A setProperties(ResultSet rs) {
    A a = new A();
    a.setName(rs.getString(...));
    ...
    return a;
}
```

I have tried taking the return from this and casting it as a B, but of course not all A's are B's... so that doesn't work. I have also tried adding another parameter to the `setProperties` method so that it takes in an A and returns an A, that way I can use polymorphism to get my B back, but then all my values were nulled out.

I'm at a loss here, any recommendations are greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Declare the method in the superclass. The subclass will override this method and then invoke `super.foo(ResultSet rs)`, where `foo(...)` is the overridden method. Therein, you can parse the `ResultSet` and set the object's fields.

**Example -**

```
class Foo{
    void setProperties(final ResultSet rs){
        // do stuff
    }
}

final class Bar extends Foo{
    @Override
    final void setProperties(final ResultSet rs){
        // do stuff
        super.setProperties(rs);
    }
}
```

For more information, see [Using the Keyword super](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/super.html).

Comment: I will have to give this a try. If I don't override the method on the subclass it should still work to set the superclass properties, right?

Comment: Right. If you don't explicitly override `setProperties` in the subclass, but still invoke it on a subclass instance, the properties will be set in the superclass.

Comment: I'm still having a problem, I'm checking name in `A.setProperties()` and it shows up fine. After the method returns I check it again in `B.setProperties()` and it's null. Any thoughts?

Comment: It really doesn't help things when you have duplicate named variables on your parent and child classes... Thank you for the help!!